# Why is my render all blurry and pixelated?

Tags: file-format, video

When I render out my blender animation project into a video file, it blurs, pixelates, and glitches in some spots. Why is this happening?
Is it because I'm using Ogg Theora with Vorbis as the format?

Example:

[image: Example]

[Blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5i33G9TR2piWUdLX2w3MVhIV2M/edit?usp=sharing)

[Output video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5i33G9TR2piUVlSUGxoUzg1d3c/edit?usp=sharing)

The input is 1080p video composited with an animation. Don't know why it's pixelating so much. Is it compression?

Comment: It looks to me like compression artifacts. To test this, try rendering a single frame (F12) and comparing it to the video.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your video output looks so bad because of the low quality setting specified in the render output.

First Things first:

You should never render out your 3d renders as movie files, NEVER! The reasons for this are:

- If you mess up the quality settings you will have to re-render from the beginning
- If you computer crashes halfway through the rendering all render will be lost and you will have to start over

The only time when you would want to render out a movie in blender is when you have an ready rendered animation as an image sequence and you want to convert it to a single movie.

The proper way:

1. Render out your animation as an image sequence. The output files should be a very high quality image which is why I would use either: png, tga, exr or whatever will yield a good looking image
2. In the blender Video Editor load the image sequence as an image sequence.
3. Now render out as a movie

---

Back to the actual question. You need to increase your render settings. Here are the important parameters you need to consider increasing:

- *Format*

  - *Bitrate*: The target amount of data per second in your video file
  - *GOP*: The number of key frames for the color palette. A value of `10` means that during those 10 frames all are drawing frames based on the same 256 colors. If your scene is changing color during this time the quality will suffer.
- *Rate*

  - *Minimum*: The lowest the *Bitrate* can be per second
  - *Maximum*: The highest the *Bitrate* can be per second

I think in your case the following settings would yield satisfactory results

[image]

Comment: If I were to render as a sequence of pngs, I could possibly ditch the compositor, render them with an alpha background, and then put them in the video sequencer with alpha over right?

Comment: I assume I might also want to drop the GOP down to 2 because there's a lot of flashing and color change in the original video. I'll try this out when I get home.

Comment: @Vader: the explanation of GOP. Where did you get the information on the use of palettes for keyframing and a 256 colour limit? Especially in regard to the theora codec. Thanks in advance.

Comment: well it's 8 bit, so that means 256 color per channel. I am not sure about the ogg format. I am just taking a swing.

Comment: I see. So it´s just an arbitrary example. Was just rereading the spec and scratching my head :-).

Comment: fell free to edit the number so that is correct.