# Why are my video renders pixelated?

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, video

[image]

I hope you can see how pixelated the face is. But the video file that is being used pre-render is very clear, and I can't figure out why blender is outputting such low quality.

Here's the information on the input files... (i haven't checked all of them but I don't mess with them so hopefully they're all the same info)

- Quicktime
- Dimensions: 1280 x 800
- Codecs: AAC, H.264
- Encoding software: Mac OS X 10.14.2 (18C54)

I've messed with blenders settings as much as I could, and can't seem to make it work.

Here's all my settings:

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

I've tried setting the output dimensions to 1280 x 800  because that's what Quicktime gives me the raw video files as... but that didn't help at all.

Any suggestions?

I'm putting these videos on YouTube if that makes a difference.

Comment: Please add some images of your pixelated output.

Comment: May be duplicate of this [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8192/why-is-my-render-all-blurry-and-pixelated?rq=1)

Comment: @Yash the first photo is pixelated. click on the image and look at the bottom right.

Comment: Is that a character? I am watching a man standing there.

Comment: @Yash It's a real life human doing a screen recording. Video editing... Edit: Anyway.. Switching to H.264 codec fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Switching the Codec to H.264 fixed the quality.

Comment: Great to hear that, playing with Blender sometimes gives you the expected results.

Comment: Thankyou, you are literally my temporary god and savior, I need to create a lovely little montage for my fam, and I kept getting a pixelated output from high quality photos, I did the same thing, I remvoed the H.264 (I forgot that in the YT tutorial, they said dont touch it)